# Tracking multiple versions (with the same url) of a webpage with google analytics and have data displayed separately for each version

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing

So I have two versions of a webpage (both with the same url), each version is shown to exactly 50 percent of webpage visitors. What is the best way to track each version and have data shown seperatly in Google Analytics for each version? This is needed for comparing which variant of the webpage works better for the visitors so ultimately I would like to compare the analytics data of both of these versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a user level custom dimension with different value based page version to send to Analytics with the pageview.

Then you can use it in the reports to distinguish the navigations of those who have visited version A from those who have seen B.